# How to exchange values between 2 records at unique column

Tags: mysql, laravel

How to exchange the values in the Unique column of two records?

like below Model

```
User
  id
  name
  code // this is unique
```

What I want to do is like...

```
$user1 = User::find(1);
$user2 = User::find(2);

DB::Transaction();
try {
    $user1->code = $user2->code;
    $user2->code = $user1->code;
    $user1->save();
    $user2->save();
} catch()...
```

of course, I know this code doesn't work by constraint violation error.

Anyway,I want to exchange UserA's code and UserB's code.
But I don't know the best way.

Any one knows?

I tried this code,and it worked.but it seems little dirty.

```
$user1 = User::find(1);
$user2 = User::find(2);

DB::Transaction();
try {
        $user1_code_temp = $user1->code;
        $user2_code_temp = $user2->code;
    $user1->code = rand();
        $user1->save();
    $user2->code = $user1_code_temp;
    $user2->save();
        $user1->code = $user2_code_temp
    $user1->save();
} catch()...
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct. And I personally would prefer it being this way as it is more readable what you are doing. You could disable unique checks in mysql temporarily but I would not recommend that.

To clean up the code, you can add this as a method in users model :

```
<?php 

// Inside User.php model
/**
 * Exchange user code
 *
 * @param  User $user
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function exchangeCode(User $user){

    $code1 = $this->code;
    $code2 = $user->code;

    $this->setCode(rand(6));

    $user->setCode($code1);

    $this->setCode($code2);

    return $this;

}

/**
 * Set Code
 * 
 * @param string $code
 *
 * @return  void
 */
public function setCode($code)
{
    $this->code = $code;
    $this->save();
    return $this;
}

// And then in controller

$user1->exchangeCode($user2);
```

Comment: it seems more smart than i did. thanks, i'll try this.

Answer (score -1):

On your model define a

```
protected $primaryKey = 'code';
```

Comment: I am trying to understand how changing the primary key column would solve the problem. If you don't mind, can you add some explanations?